# Spring ,could not resolve place holder,can someone explain me

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have never used spring before or even learnt it ,in my workplace when i run the application in tomcat ,i get the following error .I dont understand ,what this means .The placeholder is in value inside ${}. .There are no errors in the application ,i get this error in log file

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name" " ,defined in class path resource [SpringIntegration.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder "  "

Log file:

```
Oct 25, 2013 10:40:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 25, 2013 10:40:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: StartupServlet: Executing StartupServlet.init()
Oct 25, 2013 10:40:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: StartupServlet: StartupServlet.init() successfully executed
Oct 25, 2013 10:40:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 25, 2013 10:40:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'CWSJMSClient' defined in class path resource [SpringIntegration.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'VHF.CWS.Hybrid.Contract.RequestQueue'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:968)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1646)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Oct 25, 2013 10:40:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace. your question seems vague

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to use external properties in your spring configs but do not have a properly configured `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean. Refer to this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

There, you will find a detailed explanation of how to declare a properties file that contains your variable configs, such as:

```
database.username=myusername
database.password=mypassword
...
```

Then, you reference that file using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Note that you can also use the short-hand provided in the context namespace.

Comment: +1 But before using namespaces, try to learn what those namespaces are doing for you behind the scenes. (Sounds like the OP is very new to spring.)

Comment: Ah, good point @kungfuters . Learning how infrastructure components work comes in handy when you need to do something not provided out-of-the-box. . all of the magic that Spring provides is built on a few simple core components.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in a properties file

`VHF.CWS.Hybrid.Contract.RequestQueue=jms://localhost:636`